# How to create resize window with multiple disclosure triangle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsbutton, disclosure

I want to create a window like "Finder Get Info" window with multiple disclosure triangle.

I want to resize the window dynamically. Any example which explain this behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an open source framework called [SFBInspectors](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBInspectors) that can do this.  The code is a bit too lengthy to post here but should be a good start.